# How to access to worker's queued requests?

Tags: node.js, redis, cluster-computing, libuv, request-queueing

I'm implementing a web server using nodejs which must serve a lot of concurrent requests. As nodejs processes the requests one by one, it keeps them in an internal queue (in libuv, I guess).

I also want to run my web server using `cluster` module, so there will be one requests queue per worker.

**Questions:**

1. If any worker dies, how can I retrieve its queued
   requests?
2. How can I put retrieved requests into other workers' queues?
3. Is there any API to access to alive workers' requests queue?

By No. 3 I want to keep queued requests somewhere such as Redis (if possible), so in case of server crash, failure or even hardware restart I can retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the tags that you are-already-using/want-to-use redis, you can use queue-manager based on redis to do all the work for you.

Checkout https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull (or it's alternatives).

`bull` has a concept of `queue`. you add jobs to the `queue` and listen to the same queue from different processes/vms. `bull` will send the same job to only one listener and you have the ability to control how many jobs each listener is processing at the same time (`concurrency-level`).

In addition, if one of the jobs fails to run (in other words, the listener of the queue threw an error), `bull` will try to give the same job to different listener.